# Can't handle touch on node Cocos2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to figure out touch handling on multiple `CCNode`s .

I have

```
 Main CCLayer
            ------> z:2 Hud CCNode
```

On `main layer` I choose an object, on hud layer I want to control it. I followed this q&a its very helpful  [Cocos2d handling touch with multiple layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222375/cocos2d-handling-touch-with-multiple-layers)

On `Main Layer` touch events, below is Hud Node work:

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES]; 
}
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    //detects touched Object and sends it to hud 

    if (object != nil)
    {
        //sends it to hud
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event

-(void) ccTouchCancelled:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

On Hud CCNode none of ccTouchBegan/moved/ended methods are fired

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];

}
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if (object!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Touch began");
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```

EDIT:
I have a button to set speed of the object on HUD Node , it has nothing to do with `object!=nil` because when I put breakpoints I see that `-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event` is never called

```
-(void)speed1Tapped:(id)sender
{
    if (object!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Moving Object is %@:",object!=nil);
     }
}
On Log I get:
object is <ObjectATC: 0x13763850>
```

Why ccTouchBegan/moved/ended methods are not fired in CCNode?

How can I handle touches on multiple CCNodes, CCLayers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you dont receive touch method because you did not register the `touchDipatcher`

either in your `CCNodes` init method or `onEnter` method try to register it.

```
//register touches
- (void)onEnter {
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}

- (void)onExit {
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher]removeDelegate:self];
    [super onExit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your touch methods, you have a conditional that says `if (object != nil)`, but object is not defined anywhere in the code that you have shown. Is it defined elsewhere? Otherwise, this is why it is not firing.

Comment: when I put break point at any of this methods, I see that break points is never reached, besides I have buttons that control same object plse see the updated question

Comment: @MordFustang and your break point is outside of the conditional?

Comment: breakpoints don't stop unless there is code on that line if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I put break points on lines `-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher` and `-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`

Comment: @MordFustang do you call the method, `registerWithTouchDispatcher` anywhere in your code? seems like this should be called in your onEnter method in order to have it register. You will also want to unregister in your onExit method, otherwise you may get zombies attached to the touch dispatcher that will cause crashes.